# Using Azure Point-to-Site VPN, how can you access the Private endpoint enabled Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I am trying to access resources that are secured behind a private endpoint from a remote location using an Azure VPN Point-to-Site connection.

Although I can see that Azure DNS Resolver is required, I don't know how to configure Azure DNS Resolver to support Azure VPN Point-to-Site connections.

Any recommendation on configuring the Azure DNS Resolver to support Azure VPN Point-to-Site connections?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the result successfully like below.***

I have created virtual network gateway p2s configuration like below.

[image]

In your local computer open your `rootcert` certificate export & run it. copy the certificate and add like above image. then download the *vpn client -> windowsamd64 -> vpn client -> exact all->* run and connected successfully.

[image]

I have created SQL database with private endpoint:

[image]

In SQL server I have created new ***private endpoint*** with `Microsoft.sql/server` like below:

[image]

[image]

And check whether your SQL server are ***disable public access*** like below:

[image]

This private endpoint published to private dns zone here you find database server and got `A` record private address added like below.

[image]

***In private dns zone -> virtual network link -> Enable auto registration like below:***

[image]

Then I have created virtual machine to connect remote desktop with no public ip and try to change your network interface as static ip address like below:

***In your vm -> Networking -> Network interface -> Ip configuration -> click on dynamic Ip -> change assignment to be static***

[image]

Then I downloaded the RDP file connected to my vpn tunnel and connected to RDP successfully.

***In your server manager -> local server -> scroll down -> add Roles and features -> Next***

[image]

In server selection check out your vm and click next

[image]

***Find a DNS capabilities and add feature -> continue -> next***

[image]

***In Feature find -> Wins Server -> add feature -> continue -> next***

[image]

[image]

Once you install to integrate private zone ***Go to tool -> DNS -> your vm -> setup conditional forwarder -> private link:***

[image]

[image]

Add your RDP ip address to your virtual network like below:

[image]

Once you restart your Vm -> type `ipconfig /all`  add the nslookup its provide you correct ip like below:

[image]

This way we connect configuring the Azure DNS to support Azure VPN Point-to-Site connections and client can able to resolve all the domain within the dns and connected through the machine.