# Access Azure SQL Database directly via IP address

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-dns

I want to use a azure SQL Database and want connect to it via ip-adress.

My current setup:

1. Azure Database e.g. "example.database.windows.net"
2. Private Link in Azure Subnet connected with the database (10.231.1.5)
3. Azure Win VM (10.231.1.4)

When I open SSMS on my Windows VM, I can't connect to the private link database via IP-Address. It only works with the FQDN.
The error message is "Cannot open Server "10.231.1.5" requested by login"
Does somebody knows why?

In the future I want to use a P2S VPN to my local Subnet, there I dont have these Azure DNS entries.
Is it possible to make a Azure Database work only with the private IP-Address?
Otherwise I have to tell the IT-Support that they have to configure internal DNS to use a Azure DNS for Zone *.windows.net.
Is there a best practice how DNS Zones can be linked to local?

I don't want the database to be reached via public IP, so all connections must use the private link.

Comment: Note that the IP address can and does change for the primary.  Even if it were to function for connecting, it is not stable/guaranteed that it will remain the same forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this article:
https://ourcloudnetwork.com/sqlerrornumber40532-unable-to-login-to-azure-sql-db/

It's mandatory to specify the Server Name. So if i want to use only IP Address I have to specify ServerName in user field e.g.

Server: 10.231.1.5
user: myDbUser@my-example-sql-db

when i specify the name in the user field with an @ then it works like expected

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the result successfully like below.***

*****Check the Note from [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql#check-connectivity-using-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)***:**

> Use the **Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)** of the server in
> connection strings for your clients .database.windows.net`). *Any login attempts made directly to the IP address or using the private link FQDN` .privatelink.database.windows.net` shall fail*. This behavior is by design, since private endpoint routes traffic to the SQL Gateway in the region and the correct FQDN needs to> be specified for logins to succeed.

To connect with private link database, try to add virtual network subnet

***In your sql server -> Networking -> Disable Public access like below:***

[image]

Try to create a new private endpoint with `Microsoft SQL/server` like below:

[image]

Try to login your vm into remote desktop install SQL server management studio

***Now, when I try to connect with my private ip address it connected successfully like below:***

[image]

[image]

> In the future I want to use a P2S VPN to my local Subnet, there I don't have these Azure DNS entries. Is it possible to make a Azure Database work only with the private IP-Address?

You can make use of my previous [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74525568/using-azure-point-to-site-vpn-how-can-you-access-the-private-endpoint-enabled-a/74598843#74598843) Using Azure Point-to-Site VPN, you can access the Private endpoint enabled Azure SQL Database

Comment: Thanks for the comment but you use the FQDN instead of the IP thats not the way I want to use it